# How do I read json content from python file that I have made into an executable (Mac)

Tags: python, json

I recently compiled my first python program into a standalone executable. There is one problem however. My python program originally accessed a .json file within the same directory and wrote contents to it. Now that I have made my python file into an exec file, it does not seem to access the .json file in the same directory anymore. Please help!

Comment: Where's your code where you open the file?

Comment: You should've used the full path to the .json file before you compiled it

Comment: @tadman with open('config.json') as json_data_file:
        data = json.load(json_data_file)

Comment: Can you figure out the location of the executable and then compute the path based on that?

Comment: @tadman I know exactly where to find the executable, though the problem is that the executable will not look in the same or any directory for the 'config.json' file that I made (user modifies values from tkinter gui and then values save to that json file to be later used).

Comment: That's what I mean by compute the path. Expand `config.json` to the *full* path and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem occurs because the the executable is not in the same folder as your script.
I can suggest you this solution:

```
import os

# csfp - current script folder path
csfp = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
json_file = os.path.join(csfp, "config.json")
```

And you do whatever you want to do with this json_file variable, that contains the path and the name of your json file (example C:\Some_folder\My_python_project\config.json)